# afterSave redirect in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have an afterSave function in my model which saves the expiry date of some service based on the start period and duration given by the user. My `afterSave` works fine,but it is not getting redirected after saving the model instead showing a blank page.

Model:

```
public function afterSave($insert)
{

    $month= "+".$this->duration_in_months." month";
    $this->exp_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($month));
    $this->save(['exp_date']);

    return parent::afterSave($insert);
}
```

Controller:

```
if($model->save())

    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->sub_id]);

}
```

How can i redirect afterSave?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Proper way is to call the `save()` from the Controller, which will call the `afterSave()` implicitly.

You only have to do this in the Controller-Action -

`if($model->save()) {
    $this->redirect(......);
 }`

Comment: @Kunal..Its implemented in the same way only..!

Comment: So you have written the `redirect()` call in the controller and not in the `Model -> afterSave(){...}` as mentioned in the question. Still blank page is displayed? If yes, then please mention here the `redirect() call` from the controller.

Comment: Can you please also add the controller-action code that calls the `save()` in your question?

Comment: return statement is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is OK, but I see something odd in your "afterSave" method.
There is

```
$this->save(['exp_date'])
```

First of all standard ActiveRecord "save" must have boolean as its first argument.
Next is you will get recursion here - as "afterSave" method is being called inside "save" method.

So I suppose the real problem is that you don't have any error displayed. Try to enable error reporting in your index.php before including Yii:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
```

This is only for development.

Comment: In development, your php.ini should have error reporting on. No sense in messy code laying around to spit out errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\Yii::$app->response->redirect('url')->send()` for redirection from everywhere.

Your application shows blank page because you call `$this->save(['exp_date'])` in `afterSave()`. It calls `afterSave()` again and causes endless loop. You should avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But it was resolved in the following:

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);

    if ($insert) {
        $month = "+".$this->duration_in_months." month";
        $this->exp_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($month));
        $this->save(false, ['exp_date']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try `return $this->redirect();`